# Dart Socket ERROR: ../../third_party/dart/runtime/bin/socket_android.cc:147: `reusePort` not supported for Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sockets, socket.io

I'm new to flutter development. I'm building a remote app for android and iOS that will let users to control their legacy TV via infrared, and smart tv via WIFI. This exception only appears for android. On iOS app is working fine. I' using the following package to discover devices in my app.

```
upnp2: ^0.3.2
```

Here is all the dependencies used in my project.

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  rxdart: ^0.27.3
  sqflite: ^2.0.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
  ir_sensor_plugin: ^0.2.0
  introduction_screen: ^2.1.0
  network_info_plus: ^2.1.2
  ping_discover_network_forked: ^0.0.1
  web_socket_channel: ^2.1.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  upnp2: ^3.0.6
  multicast_dns: ^0.3.2
```

There is no other exception appeared in tracing. I don't know why its happening only for android while its working fine for iOS. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

the new version of `upnp2` (`3.0.10`) should have fixed this issue, sorry for the late response. Please try out again and let me know the results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).